# Find the value of the determinant $M$ from the equation $M = 3A^2 + AB + B^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

> Find the determinant $M$ if $M = 3A^2 + AB + B^2$, where $$A = \begin{vmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{vmatrix}$$ and  $$B = \begin{vmatrix} 1/2 & 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{vmatrix}$$ without evaluating $A$ and $B$ independently.

My approach was

$$\det(M) = \det( 3A^2 + AB + B^2) = \det(A+B)^2 - \det(AB) + 2\det(A^2) = \det(A+B)^2 + \det(A) \times \det(2A-B)$$

Is the approach correct?

Comment: @scoopfaze deteminant is n-linear, not linear. So $\det(A+B) \neq \det(A)+\det(B)$ generally speaking. For intuition consider the case $A+B=I_2$, $A$ is all zero except element $(1,1)$ be $1$. and $B$ is all zero except element $(2,2)$ be $1$. In this case $\det(A+B) = 1 \neq \det(A)+\det(B) = 0 + 0$

Comment: @arnav007 can you please explain more, what do you mean by "without evaluating A and B independently"?

Comment: @K.K.McDonald That's the question itself. I believe it means we can't put the value of A^2 and B^2 directly.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald, you're right. It's been a while since I've reviewed it. Cheers.

Comment: Exactly @scoopfaze Although I am not sure about the wordings, but we can't evaluate A^2 or B^2 separately I guess

Comment: The way it seems to be phrased, upon a second reading, is that you should not find the values of the determinants of $A$ or $B$ by themselves. However, I do not see the issue in solving for $M$ and then finding its determinant.

Comment: @scoopfaze doesn't not evaluating A and B independently mean that in any operation we perform, A and B should both be involved? In other words, AB or BA or such. $$A^2$$ is just solving A independently w.r.t B.

Comment: The way the problem is stated, $A$ and $B$ are just numbers, since both of them are determinants of matrices. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos A and B are matrices or numbers? If they are numbers then the matrix M is only one element?

Comment: @arnav007 You are asking me? It's *your* question! Are you aware or not of the fact that$$\begin{vmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{nn}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nn}\end{vmatrix}$$means$$\det\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\ldots&a_{nn}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&\ldots&a_{2n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\ldots&a_{nn}\end{bmatrix}?$$

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that. So that means A and B are numbers. I am solving questions from a book called "Higher Engineering Mathematics" by B.S. Grewal so I don't understand the question myself.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am getting 5 now after using the equation $$ (A+B)^2 - A(2A - B) $$ but is it correct approach?

Comment: This is definitely not correct.

Comment: @MMM doesn't det(AB) = det(BA) ?

Comment: Note that $(A+B)^2$ is not equal to $A^2+2AB+ B^2$ in general.

Comment: @MMM but Jose said that A and B are just numeric values not matrices. So it should work fine right?

Comment: That's true because of $det(AB= det(A) det(B))$.

Comment: I don't know. Can you please share the link of original question?

Comment: @MMM imgur.com/vDGvCb9

Comment: Thanks.  Now now I understand that A and B simply number. Please allow me some time to solve it.

Comment: I am sorry to say this problem is not clearly stated. Note that from the author's notation we can guess $A$ and $B$ represent some numbers. That means $M$ is also a number. However, the problem asks to evaluate the $det(M)$, which I don't understand. I am sorry I could not help.

Comment: @MMM no, thank you for helping :)

Comment: I wish I could actually help.

Comment: Indeed there has been some abuse of notation here. It should be e.g. $$A = \begin{pmatrix}2&1&1\\1&2&1\\0&-1&0\end{pmatrix} $$ and $$\det A = \begin{vmatrix}2&1&1\\1&2&1\\0&-1&0\end{vmatrix}. $$

Comment: @MMM No, the problem doesn’t ask to evaluate ”the $det(M)$;” it asks for “the determinant $(M)$.” This phrase gives the name “$M$” to this number and then the problem continues on with an expression that equals $M$. It’s not referring to some unspecified matrix $M$.

Comment: @Math1000 The notation is unfortunate, but there’s no abuse that I can see. The phrase “the determinant ($M$)” gives the name $M$ to this value that one is meant to compute and states that it’s equal to the determinant of some matrix. The problem then gives an expression for $M$ in terms of two other numbers, $A$ and $B$, that happen to themselves be equal to the determinants of two matrices. I would’ve used lower-case names for all of these values myself to avoid just this sort of confusion.

Comment: Anyways, the notation issue is now resolved, and I am happy for that although, I was confused with the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. As has already been pointed out in comments, determinants are *multilinear*. In particular, it’s not generally true that $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$. The only property of determinants introduced in the preceding material in the text that hasn’t been used in any of the other exercises is that the determinant of a product is the product of determinants, so my guess is that this problem is meant to provide you with some some practice with that. However tedious the calculation might be, it appears that you’re meant to calculate the three matrix product and then compute their determinants instead of computing $A$ and $B$ directly, which would be much less work.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much :)